# AngularJS / Javascript create $scope runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been looking at this for hours and so apologize if this is a dumb question, but is there a way in AngularJS or Javascript to do the following:

HTML
// I have a number of html piece of code (templates) for different controls

```
<button  data-action="flip" ng-click="imageControl($event)"></button>
```

// ... 10 other imagecontrol types e.g. rotate, etc.

// objective - show or hide html based on which button is pressed

```
<div ng-show="(imageControl.flip)> // html stuff </div>
```

// angular function

```
$scope.imageControl = function($event) {
   // get data-action from html element e.g. flip 
   var actionType = $event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-action");



     $scope.actionType ? $scope.actionType = false : $scope.actionType = true;

}
```

HERE IS THE QUESTION:

is there a way from me to use actionType to create and set a variable at runtime
why? so I don't have to create 10 different if statement for each control 
btw - I know this won't work, but using it to illustrate example

Comment: I hope that when I get to be a JS expert I don't have a sense of unearned arrogance to mark someone -1 for asking a question. I spent 8 years in the special forces and have never treated anyone with disrespect for asking a "dumb" military question. Always seek to be humble makes the journey through life so much more pleasant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify the issue, by not using the data attributes since angular does not need it.

markup:

```
<button  ng-click="imageControl('flip')"></button>

<div ng-show="actions.flip"> // html stuff </div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.imageControl = function(action) {
  $scope.actions[action] = !$scope.actions[action];
};
```

Comment: Brocco, you are my hero ... what a simple and elagant solution! I was heading down prototypes etc. Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem, just remember that many many times, the easier solution is the right solution. K.I.S.S. (of offense intended)

Comment: Not that this matters, but I did add $scope.actions = []; at the beginning of the function to ensure if there is an active control that and the user then clicks on another that you don't end up with the wrong control still active. Again thanks

Comment: It is good to initialize `$scope.actions` but I would create it as an object via {} not as an array []. The reason for this is that the indexers will be strings and not numbers.